# On exception email browser name and version

Tags: java, browser, servlets

I've created a servlet for sending the exception or error details to the webmaster.
I get the details like this:

```
 Throwable throwable=null;
 Object codeObj, messageObj, typeObj;
 codeObj = request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");
 typeObj = request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception_type");
 throwable = (Throwable) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception");
 uri = (String) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.request_uri");
```

Is there any way to get details like browser name and version also from my error servlet?

Comment: This post will helpful to you

[Get location and browser inforrmation][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326928/how-can-i-get-client-infomation-such-as-os-and-browser/18030465#18030465

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the browser user agent using this:

```
request.getHeader("User-Agent");
```

The version information should be in there, but reliably extracting it programmatically is difficult, since every browser user agent looks different.