# find user OS using Spring-mvc / tomcat

Tags: spring-mvc, operating-system

How can I find my user's OS in my web app, using Spring-mvc framework ?

I assume I can scan the user-agent value, but is there any existing solution/lib ? (there is so much possible values for each os...)

Thanks

Comment: The answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326928/how-can-i-get-client-infomation-such-as-os-and-browser

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript can do a [browser](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp) and [OS](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/operatin.htm) detection. Use it to initialize a hidden field which is submitted through some form or sent to the server using AJAX.

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to do the detection directly in my web app, since the information is already sent throw the user-agent.