# identify client machine Operating System by using request object in java web applications

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get client infomation such as OS and browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326928/how-can-i-get-client-infomation-such-as-os-and-browser)

i want to know clients machine Operating system name when i received request in my `servlet` 
through `request` object

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example using the [user-agent-utils](https://code.google.com/p/user-agent-utils/) library:

```
public class SomeServlet extends HttpServlet {
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
      String userAgentString = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
      UserAgent userAgent = UserAgent.parseUserAgentString(userAgentString);
      OperatingSystem os = userAgent.getOperatingSystem();

      // Do stuff with os...
  }
}
```

You can read more about the OperatingSystem class [here](https://code.google.com/p/user-agent-utils/).

You can [find the jar here.](https://code.google.com/p/user-agent-utils/downloads/detail?name=UserAgentUtils-1.2.3.jar)

Comment: find the jar here: http://mavensearch.io/repo/eu.bitwalker/UserAgentUtils/1.19

Answer (score 0):

Use user-agent HTTP header.
Here is how it looks like on my machine:

`user-agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4`

As you can see it is a freely formatted text, so you have to investigate different user agent and process them using probably regular expression.