# How to get client machine's OS name from servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to get client machine's OS name from my servlet. I have tried request.getHeader("user-agent") its not gave me correct name. Tell me any other ways...

Comment: Have a look on this [thread][1]. this look similar to you problem



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13076057/identify-client-machine-operating-system-by-using-request-object-in-java-web-app

Comment: Does it help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13076057/identify-client-machine-operating-system-by-using-request-object-in-java-web-app

Comment: Similar question but its not gave me a answer...

Comment: @KanagarajM: It would be better if you post your code to find client browser and the result string that Java returned to you.

Answer (score 0):

Deliver an HTML page with [JavaScript determining the OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514179/how-to-find-the-operating-system-version-using-javascript). This then can be sent to the server. No java class will be able to access the client PC, and only the headers sent by the browser are available to exploit.