# How to get the user's info such as os , browser and ip address if they login in my website, specifically in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, user-agent

Because I want to store them in the login tables. I have a similar topic , but this one is Java: [How can I get client infomation such as OS and browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326928/how-can-i-get-client-infomation-such-as-os-and-browser)

I'm also using Laravel.

Comment: That data ain't reliable. And how... you ask? Google 'php get client ip'

Comment: `$_SERVER` variable

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: I got the browser and OS, thanks for the link. What am I lacking is the IP address.

Answer (score 1):

I would not suggest you to use `$_SERVER` variable or some old OS/Browser lists. Detecting OS/Browser is really complicated task, that's why I'd go with specialized software like [MobileDetect](http://mobiledetect.net) and [Laravel package](https://github.com/hisorange/browser-detect) for this software.