# How can website determine os version?

Tags: javascript, html, web

How to write a website, that determines, if the user browses using a Server version of Windows?

Example:

- If the user uses `Windows Server 2016` => `Server`
- If the user uses `Windows 10` => `not Server`

Comment: First question, in order to rule out X/Y Problems - why?

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514179/how-to-find-the-operating-system-version-using-javascript), there's a good answer there.

Comment: I edited the question to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `navigator.userAgent` which will return a string containing various pieces of information, for example on my machine:

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.98 Safari/537.36"
```

So then we can do:

```
function getOS() {
    if (navigator.userAgent.includes('NT 10.0')) {
        return 'Win10';
    } else if (navigator.userAgent.includes('NT 8.1')) {
        return 'Win8.1';
    }
    //etc...
}
```

Comment: You can't rely on this.  You can change it.

Comment: but my question: 
Can I detect if it's Windows server version,  or not?)

Comment: Open a Javascript console in a browser on the server machine and type `navigator.userAgent`, give me the output and I'll update my answer.

Comment: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.75 Safari/537.36"

Comment: @user3006028 that's the Win10 string. As I say I don't know the Windows Server 2016 user agent and Google isn't proving fruitful, but I've updated my answer for win10/8.1. If you can get the user agent for 2016 then I can help you figure out what the conditional should be.

Comment: Remember includes isn't supported by IE. So it's not super useful for detecting IE. :) You can use a polyfill, but feature detection is preferred over browser detection.

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript this can be easily done. See the following link:
[Can I use JavaScript to detect the operating system on the client machine](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/operatin.htm)

Using java you could use `System.getProperty("os.name")` but this does not server your purpose since this will give you the operating system at which java is running which would be the OS of the server

I just found out this one which I think it solves your problem:

[How can I get client infomation such as OS and browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326928/how-can-i-get-client-infomation-such-as-os-and-browser)