# Source of request on tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, server

I want to know the browser which was used to hit the service deployed on tomcat server. Does tomcat maintains a log of such information? If not, then is there anything we can do to know such information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get client infomation such as OS and browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326928/how-can-i-get-client-infomation-such-as-os-and-browser)

Answer (score 0):

You can extract this information from the `HttpServletRequest` object in runtime and extract it to your logs by yourself (without being depended on your servlet container):

`String  browserDetails  =   request.getHeader("User-Agent");`

For further information take a look at:

[UserAgent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#User_agent_identification)

[List of HTTP header fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields)